# Selenium on Windows 10 Edge Browser

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I have to run automation on Windows 10 'Edge' browser. Please let me know how to launch Edge browser in windows 10 using Java Selenium Web Driver.

Comment: please add some more information of what you've tried already.

Answer (score 5):

It's for IE:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "driver/IEDriverServer.exe");
```

Go to: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212

**Download *MicrosoftWebDriver.exe***

And now your code for Edge has to be:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "driver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("www.site.com");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [WebDriverManager](https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/). Simply add this line to your Java program:

```
WebDriverManager.edgedriver().setup();
```

... and webdrivermanager downloads automatically the [Edge driver](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48212) and export the variable *webdriver.edge.driver* for you.

The webdrivermanager Maven dependency is:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
   <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.edge();
    driver = new EdgeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. The above code is working fine to launch an edge browser. Also i need a clarification whether this edge driver supports all existing functions and methods. I have this doubt because sendkeys method is not accepting String instead it is asking for charsequence. Similarly, I am getting an error when using the code "driver.manage().window().maximize();".

Comment: The application is launched and navigating to other pages are working fine but everything is happening without focus (which means just the Edge icon is highlighted in the task bar and I am unable to view whats happening with the application as it is doing everything hidden). Is this how will it behave or kindly share the solution if any. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To use Edge with Selenium, one would need to -

- have Windows 10
- download the correct version of MicrosoftWebDriver based on your OS build number

Use the steps given below -

1. Go to **Start > Settings > System > About** and note down the OS Build number
2. Download the proper version of the driver from this link - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/
3. If the file that's downloaded is .msi, then install it to get the .exe driver. For one of the release, direct .exe can be downloaded.
4. Once the MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is downloaded, we can use it in our test script using either System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "driver location") or using environment variable

Sample script would look like this -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Web Driver\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe"); //put actual location
WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
driver.get("your link");
```

Refer this article for detailed information: http://automationtestinghub.com/selenium-3-launch-microsoft-edge-with-microsoftwebdriver/